# React Native: How to make TouchableOpacity shrink to fit Text contents?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I have a `TouchableOpacity` with a `Text` component inside it in my React Native app, and I want the `TouchableOpacity` to be only as wide as the `Text`. I've tried doing this:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexBasis: 0, flexShrink: 1}}>
    <Text>text</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

But the `TouchableOpacity` is still as wide as the whole screen. `flexGrow` is 0 by default, so I figured by allowing the `TouchableOpacity` to shrink with `flexShrink` and having its `flexBasis` be zero,

Comment: I have just tried your example and it works for me. [Check it out](https://snack.expo.io/GtpwTkhr4G)

Comment: Your snack works on web, but on iOS and Android the text doesn't appear. Are you getting that too?

Comment: @gkeenley did my answer help ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the alignself style for TouchableOpacity

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: 'red', alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
    <Text>text</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```